# Using a single URL for GET and POST with Django REST Framework list_route

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

The ModelViewSets in DRF have been really helpful, but I'm trying to extend one of them to be able to return a list of objects at a GET request, and process a list on a POST request. So far, it seems like I need to use the `@list_route` decorator to add this functionality.

I've used it just fine to add custom routes in other viewsets, however this is the first time I'm trying to add one that accepts more than one method. Here's what I have so far:

```
class PickViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

  queryset = Pick.objects.all()
  serializer_class = PickSerializer

  def get_queryset(self):
    #gets the correct queryset

  @list_route(methods=['get', 'post'])
  def update_picks(self, request, league, week, format = None):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #process/save objects here
    else:
        #otherwise return the requested list
```

I think this works and that my issue is in `urls.py`- here's the related stuff from there:

```
#bind the pick methods explicitly
update_picks = PickViewset.as_view({'get': 'update_picks'})

url(r'^api/picks/(?P<league>[\w ]+)/(?P<week>[0-9]+)/$', update_picks, name='update_picks')
```

This works fine for GET requests, and if i change the `update_picks` definition to

```
update_picks = PickViewset.as_view({'get': 'update_picks'})
```

then I can step into the POST code from the Viewset. What do I need to do to have both GET and POST requests routed to the `update_picks` action, where they can then be differentiated with the request method?

I tried adding a `, {'post': 'update_picks'}` to the as_view(), but that doesn't work.

I also tried adding

```
get_picks = PickViewset.as_view({'get': 'update_picks'})
```

with new URL pattern

```
url(r'^api/picks/(?P<league>[\w ]+)/(?P<week>[0-9]+)/$', get_picks, name='get_picks'),
```

but that didn't work either.

I looked into having separate `list_routes` with the same URL, but that doesn't seem to be supported, though I could have missed something in the docs.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `actions` argument to the `ViewSet` is a dict, all methods go in that dict:

```
get_picks = PickViewset.as_view({
    'get': 'update_picks',
    'post': 'update_picks',
})
```

Comment: Whenever I try to POST multiple objects to that `list_route` action, I get a JSON error: `"detail": "JSON parse error - Extra data: line 90 column 6 - line 181 column 2 (char 3683 - 7375)"`. (this location corresponds to the end of the first object). Is it possible to handle a list of objects in this manner?